# Adjust axes limits from a script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

Is it possible to adjust the price axis limits from within a script? For example, I would like to adjust the limits of the price (y) axis based on the highest high and lowest low of the currently visible candles. If possible, how do I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

You can kinda do the opposite by polotting an invisible line but you can't really set the limits of the price axis. You also cannot get the highest/lowest visible candle information at the moment.